# visualsearchjs pass parsed values to controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

Currently trying to pass

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
        $('a[name="searchLink"]').bind('click', function() {
            })
            $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?facets=' + visualSearch.searchQuery.facets() );
        })
    })
</script>
<g:link controller="Search" action="test" name="searchLink" id="searchLink">TEST GRAILS</g:link>
```

which spits back `Object object` which isn't very useful.

I can do `visualSearch.searchQuery.value()` but then I need to parse it myself and it may not be as clean.  Is there any good way to fix this to pass in the facets?  Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us your Facet domain.

Comment: The domain is people:  So for instance it might be 
`City.name: "Boston" Person.name: "Pat" Pet.id: 5`